# php regular expression for new line and spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

i have a string like below:

```
 صفحه نخست - خبرآنلاین 





 شنبه 20 مهر 1392 - 04:18 



 data-val-required کلمه مورد جستجو الزامی است. id Keyword name Keyword type text value
```

i tried to make an array of words by `preg_split` but i need some helps on regular expression.

i used `preg_split('/ {1,}/', $text);` but it dont covered all spaces....
some new lines are in my final array..
i can to clean up array after the finish of the string by `trim` and `unset` the array element but before it i have to look for a better regular expression.

what is the best regular expression format for me!?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining `regular` and `expression` doesn't mean you're talking about regular expressions, which is covered by the `regex` tag, which was incidentally already on your question.  Please also be more selective with your tags.  You don't need to repeat yourself.  Repeating yourself isn't productive.  It would not be productive to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\s+` to match one or more empty spaces, which includes newlines.
Also, you could add a fourth parameter `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to exclude any matching spaces.

```
$foo = preg_split ("/\s+/", $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

For more information, see [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Answer (score 0):

if you have utf8 mode
you can use this.

```
$array = preg_split( '/\p{Z}+/u ' , $text );
```